# how to set error on Editext using databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want to show error on the Edittext, if input is not correct. I am doing this on the click of the button inside my activity class. Right now I am not getting anything, Please show me what is the correct way to achieve this.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <variable
        name="activity" type="com.example.SigninActivity" />
 </data>

<RelativeLayout
      <EditText
       android:id="@+id/ed_login"             
       android:layout_width="match_parent
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:digits="0123456789"
       app:errorText='@{activity.errorMsg != null ? activity.errorMsg : ""}'/>
```

Binding Adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("errorText")
fun setError(editText: EditText, str: String?) {
if(!str.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    editText.
    setError((HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
        "<font color='red'>" + str + "</font>",
        HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)))
   } 
}
```

Activity class

```
 var errorMsg: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
 
 override fun onClick(view: View) {
       val mobileNo = dataBinding.etLoginMobnum.text.toString()
       if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mobileNo) && mobileNo.length != 11) {
            errorMsg.value = "Enter Valid Number"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

to show an error on your EditText you may use TextInputEditText within TextInputLayout, like the following

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your number" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

with `app:errorEnabled="true"` in the TextInputLayout you can achieve what you want

Using it in code:

show error to the user

```
myBinding.textInputLayout.setError("Enter Valid Number")
```

to remove it

```
myBinding.textInputLayout.setError(null)
```

to use it with databinding you can do the following

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable name="myData" type="com.example.CustomDataObject"/>

    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:errorText="@{myData.errorMsg}">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Your number" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Binding Adapter

```
@BindingAdapter({"android:errorText"})
fun setError(tInputLayout: TextInputLayout, str: String) {
    if (!str.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        tInputLayout.setError("Enter Valid Number")
    } else {
        tInputLayout.setError(null)
    }
}
```

In Activity

```
myBinding.setMyData(myDataObject)
```

note: in `<data>` scope in the XML you should declare your data objects with `<variable>` tag, not your activities.

make sure you are using material library in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) for more information about DataBinding

Comment: btw you can update uour @BindingAdapter to accept nullable error message `str: String?` and then you wont need that if esle condition, just `tInputLayout.setError(str)` :)